# android populate spinner from html form values (select tag)

Tags: android, html, forms, select, spinner

Hi I'm currently looking at the best/simplest way to populate a spinner with the values from a select section of a html page. Eventually the spinner values must be exactly the same as the ones present in the html select section. I'm looking to do this in the simplest way possible. I thought of the following ideas:

- Read the values from the html page (for example using lxml)
- Add the values to the spinner (directly or if not possible after saving the values in a database)

Does anyone know the simplest way to this (for both the read part and the population part)? Is there an android object/class allowing to directly link the values from the html page to a spinner?

Many thanks in for your help!
Ben

Comment: Is the HTML page yours or are you scraping another website? In other words do you have sql access the the select values?

Comment: Exactly, the html page is from a website (not under my control)

Comment: I was just about to ask the exact same question when I refined my google search and found this posted just an hour earlier. Odd coincidence. Can anyone help? It seems like it would be a common task that someone has done already and I'm sure me and my friend here would rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I used jsoup in an AsyncTask to get the value and text of the options and put them in a text/value TreeMap (sorted HashMap) like so:

```
class TheaterGetter extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Document> {    
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        context = contexts[0];
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://landmarkcinemas.com").timeout(10000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("website connection error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return doc;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        Element allOptions = doc.select("select[id=campaign").first();
        Elements options = allOptions.getElementsByTag("option");
        options.remove(0);
        TreeMap<String, String> theaters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        for (Element option:options) {
            theaters.put(option.html(), option.attr("value"));
        }
```

Then I made this adapter for the spinner:

```
public class TreeMapSpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private TreeMap<String, String> treeMap;

    public TreeMapSpinAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, TreeMap<String, String> treeMap){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, treeMap.values().toArray());
        this.context = context;
        this.treeMap = treeMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.treeMap.values().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.treeMap.values().toArray()[arg0];
    }

    public Object getItem(String key) {
        return treeMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(treeMap.keySet().toArray()[position].toString());
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(treeMap.keySet().toArray()[position].toString());
        return label;
    }

}
```

Then, back in our AsyncTask we set up the spinner like so:

```
TreeMapSpinAdapter adapter = new TreeMapSpinAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, theaters);
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And finally we call our AsyncTask like so:

```
new TheaterGetter().execute(this);
```

Things are called theater this and that because in my case I was getting a list of theater locations.

Comment: Thank you Sajattack. I was hoping there was a more direct way which would avoid parsing the html page which is not always fun :)